# Allure report growing and taking longer to generate over time

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webdriver-io, allure

When I first installed Allure on our Jenkins pipeline, it was a short increase to the total build time and created excellent reports. The reports are still excellent, but with each build, the report grows by ~1MB and takes longer and longer to generate. At this point each report is 70MB takes 20+ mins (longer than the rest of the pipeline).

My guess is that Allure is using all of the combined test results since it was implemented into the pipeline for each new, generating larger reports and taking longer. What are my options to limit the size of the report while keeping it useful and how do I make those changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that you are clearing / deleting `allure-results` directory in between test executions

And you'll still have trends / history build - Allure Jenkins plugin builds it using previous generated report artefacts

Comment: You were right! We added a `sh 'rm -rf webdriverio-test/results/allure-results'` to remove the old results before the tests run and that significantly reduced the allure part of the build from ~30 minutes to ~20 seconds. Much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using webdriverio with javascripts and nodejs.

Try clearing your report folder before script execution starts. You can use del module for this purpose

It will look like this:

```
const del = require('del');
del(['tmp/*.js', '!tmp/unicorn.js']).then(paths => {
console.log('Deleted files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
});



Hope it helps!!
```